# Functional Programing in Scala Exercise 6.11. How does this for-comprehension work?

Tags: scala

Code here:
https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/state/State.scala

```
  def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = for {
    _ <- sequence(inputs map ((modify[Machine] _) compose update))
    s <- get
  } yield (s.coins, s.candies)
```

I don't understand how the second line `s <- get` works in this for-comprehension.

As far as I can see, the first line creates a State[Machine, List[Unit]] and flatMap throws away the List[Unit] with _.

Subsequently, in the second line, I dont get understand how `get` is being applied to the `Machine` created in the first line. How does the `Machine` get passed along?

**EDIT:**
Thanks jwvh and Markus Appel for the replies, I get now that `get` is a method with no parameters that returns a `State[S, S]`.

Now I think I get it but please correct me if i'm wrong.
First, I expanded the for-comprehension as per below.

```
sequence(inputs map ((modify[Machine] _) compose update))
    .flatMap(_ => get
        .map(s => (s.coins, s.candies))
```

`get.map(s => (s.coins, s.candies)` can be substituted with `State(s => (s, s)).map(s => (s.coins, s.candies)` and eventually `State(s => (s, (s.coins, s.candies)))`

```
sequence(inputs map ((modify[Machine] _) compose update))
    .flatMap(_ => State(s => (s, (s.coins, s.candies))))
```

Substituting the outer `sequence(inputs map ((modify[Machine] _) compose update)).flatMap` with the definition, I see

```
State(s => {
    val (a, s1) = sequence(inputs map ((modify[Machine] _) compose update)).run(s)
    f(a).run(s1)
  })
```

Now I substitute `f(a)` with an evaluation of `_ => State(s => (s, (s.coins, s.candies)))`

```
State(s => {
    val (a, s1) = sequence(inputs map ((modify[Machine] _) compose update)).run(s)
    State(s => (s, (s.coins, s.candies))).run(s1)
  })
```

Essentially, the `sequence(inputs map ((modify[Machine] _) compose update))` produces a `Machine` in the final state after executing the list of inputs and produces an output of type `State[Machine, List[Unit]]`. But the actual `Machine` within this State is not passed along explicitly. Rather it is passed along implicitly by `flatMap` definition when it calls `State(s => (s, (s.coins, s.candies))).run(s1)` via `.run(s1)`.

Comment: `get` is a method (line 213) in `object State` (line 175). At line 162 all methods of object `State` are imported into the current scope so they can be accessed without a path reference.

Comment: I once understood what this code do when reading the book, not anymore :-(

Comment: "...it is passed along implicitly..." An inaccurate and ill-advised choice of words. Implicit/implicitly has a precise meaning in Scala and it doesn't apply here as nothing is placed into, or required of, the implicit namespace.

Comment: How would you phrase it? Good point, there is a specific meaning for the word implicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jwvh already pointed out, `get` is a method defined in `object State`.
The `get`-method is neither applied to any `Machine` nor is a `Machine` used as parameter, because the function has the following signature:

```
def get[S]: State[S, S] = State(s => (s, s))
```

This means `get` has no parameters and the return type is `State[S, S]`.