# Can't figure out syntax in scala compose function

Tags: scala

I am working through the red book and when checking my answers for the exercises , I found that the solution for one of the exercises (6.11) was quite different (and much more elegant and cryptic than my own solution).

Here is the code:

```scala
object Candy {
  def update: Input => Machine => Machine = (i: Input) => (s: Machine) =>
    (i, s) match {
      case (_, Machine(_, 0, _)) => s
      case (Coin, Machine(false, _, _)) => s
      case (Turn, Machine(true, _, _)) => s
      case (Coin, Machine(true, candy, coin)) =>
        Machine(false, candy, coin + 1)
      case (Turn, Machine(false, candy, coin)) =>
        Machine(true, candy - 1, coin)
    }

  def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = for {
    _ <- State.sequence(inputs map (modify[Machine] _ compose update))
    s <- get
  } yield (s.coins, s.candies)

  def modify[S](f: S => S): State[S, Unit] = for {
    s <- get // Gets the current state and assigns it to `s`.
    _ <- set(f(s)) // Sets the new state to `f` applied to `s`.
  } yield ()

  def get[S]: State[S, S] = State(s => (s, s))

  def set[S](s: S): State[S, Unit] = State(_ => ((), s))
```

The bit I am unsure of is this line:
`inputs map (modify[Machine] _ compose update)`

I understand how compose works but this particular syntax is really throwing me for a loop. Is there a way that this can be rewritten that is not so compact that would help a noob understand?

Thanks in advance.

Also for anyone else trying to better understand how this code works, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587641/functional-programing-in-scala-exercise-6-11-how-does-this-for-comprehension-wo) post I found helpful.

Comment: Sure just `inputs.map((x => modify[Machine](x)).compose(update))` Being honest, I would also recommend something less cryptic for real code.

Comment: Hmm, looks to me like `inputs.map(input => modify[Machine](update(input)))` because `update(input)` returns `Machine => Machine` which looks like what you should pass to `modify()`.

Comment: "elegant" and "cryptic" are nearly antonyms in this context. If you find the code cryptic, then it's not elegant.

Comment: Appreciate the comments! The first comment doesn't compile. The second does and looks to work as expected - still not sure why it works though as `update` doesn't take any parameters. Could you provide an example using `compose`?

Comment: Right when I pressed enter, I realized why I "think" it works. update returns a function that takes an `Input`. So by passing an input to update this is actually returning another function that of `Machine => Machine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened to stumble upon this. For anyone reading this, the underscore in `inputs map (modify[Machine] _ compose update)` is eta expansion, ie the `_` translates the method into a function allowing this to be further composed to create a function of the form `Input => State[Machine, Unit]`.

```
val t: Function1[Input, State[Machine, Unit]] = modify[Machine] _ compose update
```

Note that in `scala3`, this eta expansion takes place automagically and the `_` syntax is not needed.

Comment: Doesn't this answer directly contradict the answer from @Jorg that _you_ marked as the accepted answer?

Comment: It does - I marked this answer originally because I _thought_ it was correct but only happened to stumble upon it after having a better understanding of eta expansion. Part of me just assumed it was correct too bc of the very high reputation :). Does my answer sound agreeable? If so, I will make this change.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of syntax features in use here:

## [Operator Syntax](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#infix-operations)

Scala allows message sends to use whitespace instead of a period as the message sending operator, i.e.

```scala
foo.bar(baz, quux)
```

can also be written as

```scala
foo bar(baz, quux)
```

## Operator Syntax, part 2

When using operator syntax with a single argument list with a single argument, the parentheses can be left off, i.e.

```scala
foo bar(baz)
```

can also be written as

```scala
foo bar baz
```

## [Placeholder syntax](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions)

Anonymous functions in Scala can be written using the underscore `_` as a placeholder for the arguments. Roughly speaking, each underscore is replaced with each argument for the closest lexically enclosing anonymous function, in order of appearance in the source text, i.e.

```scala
val adder: (Int, Int) => Int = (x, y) => x + y
```

can also be written as

```scala
val adder: (Int, Int) => Int = _ + _
```

## **NOT** [η-expansion](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#method-values)

[The underscore `_` has many uses in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8000903/2988), so sometimes if you don't look careful enough, you might confuse different usages. In this case, at a cursory glance, it *seems* like the underscore `_` could mean that `modify` is η-expanded into a method value, but that is not the case. The underscore `_` is an anonymous function argument placeholder.

## Conclusion

So, if we put the above three syntax features together, the snippet in question desugars to

```scala
inputs.map(
//    ↑ Operator Syntax
  (
    f => modify[Machine](f)
//  ↑ Placeholder Syntax ↑
  ).compose(update)
// ↑ Operator Syntax
)
```

If you ever have doubts about what the syntax of a particular piece of code means, you can print out the internal state of the Scala compiler or the Scala REPL / "interpreter" at various phases using the `-Xprint:<name-of-phase>` command line option to `scala`. For example, this is what `-Xprint:parser` prints for the snippet in question:

```scala
inputs.map((modify[Machine]: (() => <empty>)).compose(update))
```

And this is `-Xprint:typer`:

```scala
inputs.map[this.State[this.Machine, Unit]](
  (
    (f: this.Machine => this.Machine) => $anon.this.State.modify[this.Machine](f)
  ).compose[this.Input](Candy.this.update)
)
```